# Javascript array not getting the array result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" onblur="tournamentPrize(this.value);" placeholder="Player Number" id="player_number" name="data[Tournament][player_number]">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function tournamentPrize(v){
        var myArray=[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128];
        var field_val = v;
        if(myArray.indexOf(field_val)==-1){ //alert(myArray.indexOf(field_val));
            if(field_val==2){
                $('#_1st_prize').removeAttr('disabled');                
                $('#_2nd_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#_2nd_prize').val('');               
                $('#_3rd_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#_3rd_prize').val('');
                $('#_4th_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#_4th_prize').val('');               
                $('#rest_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#rest_prize').val('');
            }else if(field_val==4){
                $('#_1st_prize').removeAttr('disabled');                
                $('#_2nd_prize').removeAttr('disabled');            
                $('#_3rd_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#_3rd_prize').val('');
                $('#_4th_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#_4th_prize').val('')
                $('#rest_prize').removeAttr('disabled');
            }else{
                           alert("You have entered "+field_val+" number");
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("You have entered wrong number"); 
        }
    }
```

I have calling tournamentPrize() function in onblur this field when i entered any number it is not showing the proper  result. always display **-1**

I want to get my proper result when i will enter 2,4,8,16,32,64 and 128 But if i am entered any number except above number the result also showing wrong.

Suppose i want to enter 3 the alert box will be come ***alert("You have entered wrong number");*** but it is showing ***alert("You have entered 3 number");***

Please somebody help me

Comment: should be `if (myArray.indexOf(field_val) !== -1)`

Comment: Maybe you are also searching a polyfill of `.indexOf()` for Internet Explorer < 9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: I have using mozilla Firefox 26.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function tournamentPrize(v){
        var myArray=[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128];

        var field_val = +v; // convert value to number from string
        // OR var field_val = parseInt(v); OR var field_val = Number(v);

        if(myArray.indexOf(field_val) !== -1){ //entered valid value in array
            if (field_val==2) {
               ....
            } else if(field_val==4){
               .....
            } else{
               alert("You have entered "+field_val+" number");
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("You have entered wrong number"); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Showing Wrong result if i entered 2 it is showing `alert("You have entered wrong number"); `

Comment: first check you are getting the field_val properly ?

Comment: `var field_val = +v; // convert value to number from string`

Comment: try this to convert the string value to numner

Comment: Yes it works I have using field_val = parseInt(v); Also your code is working Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)** `onblur` I have created a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek19/4a3sR/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 function tournamentPrize(v){
    var myArray=[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128];
    var field_val = v;
    if(myArray.indexOf(field_val)!=-1){ //alert(myArray.indexOf(field_val));
        if(field_val==2){
            $('#_1st_prize').removeAttr('disabled');                
            $('#_2nd_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#_2nd_prize').val('');               
            $('#_3rd_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#_3rd_prize').val('');
            $('#_4th_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#_4th_prize').val('');               
            $('#rest_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#rest_prize').val('');
        }else if(field_val==4){
            $('#_1st_prize').removeAttr('disabled');                
            $('#_2nd_prize').removeAttr('disabled');            
            $('#_3rd_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#_3rd_prize').val('');
            $('#_4th_prize').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#_4th_prize').val('')
            $('#rest_prize').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
                       alert("You have entered "+field_val+" number");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("You have entered wrong number"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have entered 8 it is Showing the alert message `alert("You have entered wrong number"); `

Comment: it will give u the alert("You have entered wrong number");
becoz u are entering the position no in the array to be assesed and not the no. 8

Comment: :P How to match the array value with my field value?